# How do I remove Kubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, desktop-environments

I have installed Kubuntu on my Ubuntu 16.04 install.

After running apt-get remove ... and apt-get purge I STILL have kubuntu installed. Apps that were installed with Kubuntu like Konsole is still installed, Kubuntu loading screen shows on boot up, and I can still select Plasma as my desktop on logon.

How do I just revert back to plain Ubuntu completely????

Answer (score 0):

It is often very difficult to remove a [second] desktop environment completely without damage on the original desktop environment. I think you have to live with these glitches or reinstall standard Ubuntu to get a clean Unity desktop environment again.

-o-

I have a system with Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and lubuntu-desktop installed. It is mainly run as Lubuntu, and it works well for me.

I would not combine Unity with any other desktop environment. Instead I would try other desktop environments live, ['Try Kubuntu ...'](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389), or install a separate system in its own partition, drive, computer or in a virtual machine.